# Profit optimal algorithm for market clearing

Tags: programming, futures, financial-markets, algorithm

There is a well known **offline profit optimal** algorithm for market clearing (matching buy-bids with sell-bids, [visit for more details](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Esandholm/online_clearing.jacm.pdf)) which is based on bipartite weighted matching. This algorithm assumes that all buy-bids and sell-bids have quantity $= 1$.

**Question:**

What is the **offline profit-optimal** algorithm for market clearing with an arbitrary quantities for each bid?

***Note:*** simply splitting all bids into 1 quantity bids won't work, because quantity can be arbitrary float number.